# Client doesn't get a response from Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, response, thin, puma

The following happen in Thin and Puma

I have a Gallery model and a simple `remote: true` form which create a simple gallery and a button afterwards to destroy it

With Puma and Thin, if I, sometimes, do 2 (manual) consecutive actions (like create a gallery and then destroy a gallery or destroy 2 galleries one after another, I can see that Rails gets that requests, work on it and sends a js response. But the browser doesn't seem to get the response as if the response never reached it..

In chrome inspect I see that the POST (for creating a gallery) or the DELETE (for deleting) does not get a response at all, even though rails logs clearly show that the DB doing work accordingly and the JS response gets rendered

starting rails with `rails s`on development. Note that this also happens in development as well as Heroku production

I am really stumped and have no idea how to debug this, since it is obvious that Rails works..

I am using OS X 10.9.3, latest chrome, ruby 2.1.2, rails 4.1.1

Update:

Another interesting part is that I can make this happen in fairly high rate in chrome (logged in or incognito) but I can't recreate this in safari

this is my gemfile in case of something you may think may conflict and cause this havoc

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.1.2'

gem 'rails', '~> 4.1.1'
gem 'pg', '~> 0.17'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 3.1.0'
gem "rack-timeout", '~> 0.0.4'
gem 'mobile-fu'
gem 'devise', '~> 3.2.3'
gem 'omniauth-facebook', '~> 1.6.0'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '3.1.1.0'
gem "select2-rails", '~> 3.5.4'
gem "paperclip", '~> 4.1.1'
gem 'aasm'
gem 'heroku_rails_deflate', :group => :production
gem 'koala'
gem 'thin'
gem 'geocomplete_rails'
gem 'geocoder'
gem 'rails-timeago', '~> 2.0'
gem 'kaminari'
gem 'mailboxer', '~> 0.11'
gem 'newrelic_rpm'
gem 'remotipart', '~> 1.2.1'
gem "best_in_place", github: 'gmitrev/best_in_place', branch: "rails-4"
gem 'asset_sync', '~> 1.0.0'
gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 1.43.0'
gem 'paypal-sdk-rest', '0.6.1'
gem 'pacejs_rails', '~> 0.5.1'
gem 'font-awesome-sass', '4.1.0'
gem "imagesLoaded_rails", "~> 3.1.5"
gem 'slick_rails'
gem 'fittextjs_rails', '~> 1.2.0.1'
gem 'rollbar'
gem 'exception_notification', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'mixpanel-ruby'
gem 'hammerjs_rails', '1.1.3.1'
```

logs:

3 requests, post, delete and post. The last post seems ok in the logs but in the browser nothing happens

```
Started POST "galleries" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-16 11:11:30 +0300
Processing by GalleriesController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "gallery"=>{"title"=>"asdsdfc"}, "commit"=>"Create Photos Collection"}
  SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "galleries" ("created_at", "galleriable_id", "galleriable_type", "title", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", "2014-06-16 08:11:30.060558"], ["galleriable_id", 1112], ["galleriable_type", "Shop"], ["title", "asdsdfc"], ["updated_at", "2014-06-16 08:11:30.060558"]]
   (5.7ms)  COMMIT
  Photo Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "photos".* FROM "photos"  WHERE "photos"."photoable_id" = $1 AND "photos"."photoable_type" = $2  [["photoable_id", 139], ["photoable_type", "Gallery"]]
  User Load (1.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 6  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1

  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "shops".* FROM "shops"  WHERE "shops"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1112]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "brands".* FROM "brands"  WHERE "brands"."id" IN (1073)
  Rendered galleries/_new_gallery_form.html.erb (7.0ms)
  Rendered galleries/create.js.erb (48.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 74ms (Views: 49.5ms | ActiveRecord: 12.3ms)
user: me
localhost:3000/galleries


Started DELETE "/shops/1112/galleries/123" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-16 11:11:32 +0300
Processing by GalleriesController#destroy as JS
  Parameters: {"shop_id"=>"1112", "id"=>"123"}
  Gallery Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "galleries".* FROM "galleries"  WHERE "galleries"."galleriable_id" = $1 AND "galleries"."galleriable_type" = $2 AND "galleries"."id" = $3  ORDER BY created_at ASC LIMIT 1  [["galleriable_id", 1112], ["galleriable_type", "Shop"], ["id", 123]]
   (0.4ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.7ms)  DELETE FROM "galleries" WHERE "galleries"."id" = $1  [["id", 123]]
   (0.9ms)  COMMIT
  Rendered galleries/destroy.js.erb (1.5ms)
  User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 6  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
Completed 200 OK in 81ms (Views: 20.3ms | ActiveRecord: 7.7ms)
user: me
localhost:3000/galleries/123




Started POST "/galleries" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-16 11:11:34 +0300
Processing by GalleriesController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "gallery"=>{"title"=>"ads"}, "commit"=>"Create Photos Collection", "shop_id"=>"1112"}
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "galleries" ("created_at", "galleriable_id", "galleriable_type", "title", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", "2014-06-16 08:11:34.671202"], ["galleriable_id", 1112], ["galleriable_type", "Shop"], ["title", "ads"], ["updated_at", "2014-06-16 08:11:34.671202"]]
   (1.3ms)  COMMIT
  Rendered galleries/_new_gallery_form.html.erb (4.9ms)
  Rendered galleries/create.js.erb (26.9ms)
Completed 200 OK in 49ms (Views: 30.8ms | ActiveRecord: 5.4ms)
user: me
localhost:3000/galleries
```

request header (of last POST)

```
Request URL:http://localhost:3000/galleries
Request Headers CAUTION: Provisional headers are shown.
Accept:*/*;q=0.5, text/javascript, application/javascript, application/ecmascript, application/x-ecmascript
Cache-Control:no-cache
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Origin:http://localhost:3000
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://localhost:3000/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36
X-CSRF-Token:HdEQ4s5q2tkOjnbBStFfI4hQElkDYD/c1XXR8utL5XE=
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Form Dataview sourceview URL encoded
utf8:✓
gallery[title]:sdf
commit:Create Photos Collection
```

Comment: Does the response header match request header?

Comment: thats exactly the problem.. I am not getting a response. I've added the request header to the question

Comment: Just guessing: is it possible you have a js error in your first response? Thus effectively halting all js processing? Or in any js code? Check your javascript console.

Comment: I wish that would be the case, on webrick the same code works, and on thin/puma with safari it also works. Further more, the first and 2nd http requests work fine. Also, after the stuck POST gets stuck, if I continue doing action on the page they behave normally.

Comment: @nathanvda I am not getting errors as the js code the for the destroy is just `$("#gallery-<%= @gallery.id %>").hide('slow');`

Comment: If I understand correctly: you start a new js call while one is still busy (not yet processed), correct? Seems like somehow your callback (or rails callbacks) are messed up: like processing one answer, "forgets" the pending requests. However, I would expect the "response" to still show in Chrome. Mmmmmmmm. Stumped.

Comment: no, I start a new js call after the one before is finished